# How does one import/incorporate just the blog section of a WordPress site?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, content-management-system, blogs

I'm in the process of completely re-coding a client's website. Their current site is using WordPress for their blog only; The rest of the website is just hand-coded PHP. Their entire new site will be utilizing WordPress.

My question is, how do I import just the existing blog database into my current WordPress setup? In other words, I've installed a fresh WordPress into the new website's directory, and already added a bunch of pages and custom post types. Now I have to import all of the blog posts and comments from the old site, but I'm afraid of overwriting everything currently in the new database. How can I import the posts and comments without altering anything I've already completed?

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by doing following steps:

**1)** Go to old wp admin panel and click **Tools > Export**, on opening page select `Post` from options and click export

[image]

**2)** After export XML, go to your new wp site admin panel and click **Tools > Import**. If it is first time to import, you will see a selection page for importer. Select Wordpress and install wordpress importer

[image]

**3)** You are near to complete. Open up Wordpress importer and upload XML file which you have export and downloaded from old wp site.

[image]

That's it. You can see your posts and comments on your new wp site